# How do you add books to the Kindle app for iOS?

Tags: applications, ios, file-transfer

I might be overlooking something very obvious here but I cannot see any of the books I add to the Kindle app. Listed below are the steps I follow to add the books.

```
1. Connect the iPod Touch to my Windows computer and start iTunes.
2. On iTunes, go to the Apps Section of iPod Touch.
3. Using the new file transfer system with the iOS 4 (see screenshot), add the PDF and epub file type.
```

-And voila, that should have done it.
-But when I check the Kindle app on the iPod Touch, it only has the three default books it came with when I downloaded the app. (See screenshot below screenshot)

I'm sure this is some error on my part but can't figure out what.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the Archived Items folder? I think that's where stuff is on the Mac version, so it may be worth a shot.

Comment: Also, I don't believe the Kindle app supports ePub documents.

Comment: @Nathan Looked under the archived items in hope that the books might appear there. But it's empty. And I don't really mind if the ePub format doesn't work or is not supported; most of my books are in PDF anyway. I was just trying another file format to see if it helped. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: The archived items menu contains books you have purchased (or got for free) from Amazon, but that you have deleted from your device. This is where you go to redownload them to your device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kindle iphone app does not read `pdf` or `epub` files without conversion.

There are various tools you can use to convert from `pdf` and `epub` to the `mobi` format that the Kindle app can read. The one I use is [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), and it works pretty well. Epub files generally convert without problem, but pdf files might be harder, depending on how complex the pdf is. If there are pictures or columns you are probably in trouble.

Comment: How did you know this? I went through the help document and did not find any mention of supported formats. There's one about only *.azw, *.txt, *.mobi and *.prc are the only supported formats for the 1st generation kindle. Is it the same for Kindle iOS app? Have you seen any documentation mentioning this? Just asking ....

Comment: I tried to find some kind of definite proof that I could link to, but could not. I've tried it and it hasn't worked, and a couple months ago I researched this and I found some message boards that said it wasn't possible. Unfortunately, I couldn't find them again today. Also, PDF support is hard for an iPhone app from a user interface point of view, so if Kindle had built it into the app, I assume they would have at least mentioned it somewhere.

Comment: thanks anyway ... I was gonna use the Kindle app as a reader for my files but seeems it'll be useful only if my Amazon account has a lot of books. Simply adding books via the file transfer method is not primary way of using the app (unless all the books are converted to the correct format, which would be a pain)

Comment: The Kindle Personal Document Service can convert and deliver the following types of documents:
Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)
HTML (.htm, .html) 
Text (.txt) documents
Archived documents (zip , x-zip) and compressed archived documents
Mobi book

Images that are of type JPEGs (.jpg), GIFs (.gif), Bitmaps (.bmp), and PNG images (.png).
Adobe PDF (.pdf) documents are delivered without conversion to Kindle DX, Second Generation and Latest Generation Kindles.

Adobe PDF (.pdf) can be converted to Kindle format and delivered on an experimental basis.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is not to use the Kindle reader for epub or pdf files, but instead of use iBooks for those.  It will display both of them very well without any conversion required, and it's free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm gonna use iBooks to avoid converting.

Comment: I use iBooks for pdfs, but I convert epubs and use the Kindle app because it is more responsive and less ugly.

Comment: @nathang ... will give this a try as well ....